# Typeerror in pandas when idxmax()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, typeerror

I have the following dataframe:

```
    OI  CHNG IN OI  VOLUME  IV  LTP     CHNG    BID QTY     BID PRICE   ASK PRICE   ASK QTY
STRIKE PRICE                                        
17,450.00   NaN     NaN     26  19.45   1.40    -4.05   600     1.15    2.10    500
17,500.00   351     351     772     20.06   1.35    -3.15   2,050   1.35    1.65    450
17,550.00   4   4   13  21.81   2.00    -1.65   600     1.25    2.45    300
17,600.00   1   1   1   21.91   1.60    -1.40   600     1.25    1.95    300
17,650.00   NaN     NaN     7   22.15   1.35    -1.05   2,000   1.05    1.95    300
```

When i do `put['OI'].idxmax()` it throws error:

> TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Earlier I did this. `put.replace('-', np.nan, inplace = True)` to replace the dash but  i am still getting the same error.

I did some looking and it seems like its because it was looking for numeric dtype but as you can see from the below df, the dtype is numbers:

```
df['OI']
STRIKE PRICE
15,200.00        39
15,250.00        14
15,300.00        60
15,350.00        10
15,400.00       199
15,450.00        25
15,500.00       925
15,550.00       131
15,600.00       634
15,650.00       120
15,700.00     1,290
15,750.00       887
15,800.00     4,039
15,850.00     1,207
15,900.00     6,504
15,950.00     1,503
16,000.00    10,704
16,050.00     2,366
16,100.00     9,328
16,150.00     3,348
16,200.00    17,240
16,250.00     9,100
16,300.00    18,938
16,350.00     3,685
16,400.00    15,145
16,450.00     3,654
16,500.00    16,496
16,550.00     2,053
16,600.00     8,982
16,650.00     1,156
16,700.00     6,872
16,750.00       849
16,800.00     4,026
16,850.00       339
16,900.00     3,167
16,950.00        13
17,000.00     6,160
17,050.00       197
17,100.00       641
17,150.00         1
17,200.00       373
17,250.00       NaN
17,300.00        66
17,350.00       236
17,400.00       551
17,450.00       NaN
17,500.00       351
17,550.00         4
17,600.00         1
17,650.00       NaN
Name: OI, dtype: object
```

I am not sure why i am getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's because there are `,` in your column. Try replacing them with a `.`, converting to `float`, and re-running to get your `idxmax()`:

```
>>> df['col'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float).idxmax()
6
```

Data used

```
>>> df.to_dict()
{'STRIKE PRICE': {0: '15,200.00',
  1: '15,250.00',
  2: '15,300.00',
  3: '15,350.00',
  4: '15,400.00',
  5: '15,450.00',
  6: '15,500.00',
  7: '15,550.00',
  8: '15,600.00',
  9: '15,650.00',
  10: '15,700.00',
  11: '15,750.00',
  12: '15,800.00',
  13: '15,850.00',
  14: '15,900.00',
  15: '15,950.00',
  16: '16,000.00',
  17: '16,050.00',
  18: '16,100.00',
  19: '16,150.00',
  20: '16,200.00',
  21: '16,250.00',
  22: '16,300.00',
  23: '16,350.00',
  24: '16,400.00',
  25: '16,450.00',
  26: '16,500.00',
  27: '16,550.00',
  28: '16,600.00',
  29: '16,650.00',
  30: '16,700.00',
  31: '16,750.00',
  32: '16,800.00',
  33: '16,850.00',
  34: '16,900.00',
  35: '16,950.00',
  36: '17,000.00',
  37: '17,050.00',
  38: '17,100.00',
  39: '17,150.00',
  40: '17,200.00',
  41: '17,250.00',
  42: '17,300.00',
  43: '17,350.00',
  44: '17,400.00',
  45: '17,450.00',
  46: '17,500.00',
  47: '17,550.00',
  48: '17,600.00',
  49: '17,650.00'},
 'col': {0: '39',
  1: '14',
  2: '60',
  3: '10',
  4: '199',
  5: '25',
  6: '925',
  7: '131',
  8: '634',
  9: '120',
  10: '1,290',
  11: '887',
  12: '4,039',
  13: '1,207',
  14: '6,504',
  15: '1,503',
  16: '10,704',
  17: '2,366',
  18: '9,328',
  19: '3,348',
  20: '17,240',
  21: '9,100',
  22: '18,938',
  23: '3,685',
  24: '15,145',
  25: '3,654',
  26: '16,496',
  27: '2,053',
  28: '8,982',
  29: '1,156',
  30: '6,872',
  31: '849',
  32: '4,026',
  33: '339',
  34: '3,167',
  35: '13',
  36: '6,160',
  37: '197',
  38: '641',
  39: '1',
  40: '373',
  41: 'NaN',
  42: '66',
  43: '236',
  44: '551',
  45: 'NaN',
  46: '351',
  47: '4',
  48: '1',
  49: 'NaN'}}

# Check dtypes
>>> df.dtypes

STRIKE PRICE    object
col             object

# Run idxmax()
>>> df.idxmax()

TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype
```

Comment: I think that `,` can't replaced by `.` because is not an decimal separator

Answer (score 1):

You column are `dtype:object`, `.idxmax()` operate on numerical dtype.

Try:

```py
put['OI'].apply(lambda x : float(x.replace(',',''))).idxmax()
```

It'll remove comma from the numerical string and convert to float

Comment: I did `put['OI'].apply(lambda x : float(x.replace(',',''))).idxmax()` but am getting `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox strange, in my test works using the same data as @sophocles,
anyway, their code works better, just check if you wanna replace `","` to `""` or `"."`